# React Jest Test Failing - type.toUpperCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to write tests using `Jest` for `React`. However, I'm getting the following error:

> `TypeError: type.toUpperCase is not a function`

**React (images.js):**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Images extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="images">

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Test (Jest):**

```
jest.autoMockOff();

import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

const ImagesComponent = require('../src/Components/images');

describe('ImagesComponent', () => {
    it('Render instance of div class=images in DOM', () => {
        const shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
        shallowRenderer.render(<ImagesComponent className="images" />);
        imagesDivComponent = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
        expect(imagesDivComponent.props.className).toEqual('images');
    });
});
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `toUpperCase()` function?  That section of code is not provided in your question.

Comment: I'm not, that's the issue. I have fixed it though, by changing the way I define my React component, using `var Images = React.createClass ({` instead of export class, and then adding `module.exports = Images;` to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your React component from:

```
export class Images extends Component {...}
```

to:

```
var Images = React.createClass ({...)};
module.exports = Images;
```